# Extracting parts of a factor

Tags: r

I am trying to extract parts of a factor within a `data.frame` that looks like following:

```
aug$V5 <- c("00:00:00","01:01:05","04:32:22")
```

The format is in a factor and I want to extract the first two digits, as they are the hours that I am interested in and place them in a different column within my vector:

Output looks like this:

```
aug$hours <- c("00","01","04")
```

I think I just need to use the sub function but I am unsure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lubridate` to the rescue

```
> v <- c("00:00:00","01:01:05","04:32:22")
> library(lubridate)
> hour(hms(factor(v)))
[1] 0 1 4
```

or just take a substring

```
> substr(factor(v),1,2)
[1] "00" "01" "04"
```

Comment: Base dates via `as.POSIXlt` = `as.POSIXlt(v,format="%H:%M:%S")$hour`

Answer (score 1):

Or using some base R dates manipulations

```
V5 <- factor(c("00:00:00","01:01:05","04:32:22"))
as.POSIXlt(paste(Sys.Date(), V5))$hour
## [1] 0 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If i create a simple example factor here

```
V5 <- factor(c("00:00:00","01:01:05","04:32:22"))
```

then running

```
gsub("^(\\d{2}).*","\\1",as.character(V5))
```

returns

```
[1] "00" "01" "04"
```

as desired.

Comment: No need for `as.character`, it will be coerced

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
V5 <- factor(c("00:00:00","01:01:05","04:32:22"))

data.frame(strsplit(as.character(V5), ':'))[1,]
  c..00....00....00.. c..01....01....05.. c..04....32....22..
1                  00                  01                  04
```

One can just ignore the names above, or:

```
setNames(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(V5), ':'))[1,],seq(length(V5)))
   1  2  3
1 00 01 04
```

Even better would be following as suggested by @ Ananda Mahto in comments below:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(V5), ':'), '[[', 1) 
[1] "00" "01" "04"
```

Comment: I would think that `sapply(strsplit(as.character(V5), ':'), `[[`, 1)` would be more appropriate than a single-row `data.frame`.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto: Thanks for the tip. I have added this to the answer.